# Mount Oculus Go's internal storage under Linux?

Tags: mount, usb, storage

When connected to my Linux machine, `dmesg` shows the USB device without identifying or providing a device path in  `/dev`.

What steps are necessary to mount Oculus Go's internal storage under Linux? Oculus has only provided instructions for Windows, Mac, and ChromeOS in their [supporting documentation](https://support.oculus.com/212288649367669/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @slm noted in his answer, the only way to interact with the Go headset storage in Linux is to use `adb`. Some distros have packages available, for example Debian has `android-tools-adb` and Arch provides `android-tools`.

1. You must [enable Oculus Go developer mode](https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/mobilesdk/latest/concepts/mobile-device-setup-go/) using the Oculus app on your phone, which requires registering a developer organization with Facebook.
2. Linux needs to know device info. I added the following udev rule to `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules`

   ```
   SUBSYSTEMS=="usb",ATTR{idVendor}=="2833",ATTR{idProduct}=="0086",MODE="0666",GROUP="plugdev",OWNER="CHANGEME"
   ```

Then reload udev rules with `sudo udevadm control --reload-rules` (or a reboot).  If you don't have a plugdev group, you can probably omit it from the rule or just create it with `groupadd plugdev` and add your user with `usermod -aG USER plugdev`.

3. The headset will prompt you to trust your connected USB device every time you plug it in.

At this point, your basic adb syntax should work. If you don't get a prompt on your headset when you plug it into USB, then you may need to perform a factory reset on the headset and start over (I had to do this). You should see the device when you run `adb devices`.  You can `adb shell` to browse the local storage and `adb push <files> /mnt/sdcard` to copy your files over.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to install ADB to be able to work with Oculus Go. It's an Android based app. Google provides downloads for the pieces here: [How to Install ADB on Windows, macOS, and Linux](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools).

Full details from XDA Developers Forums:

> 1. How to Install ADB on Linux
> 2. Download the ADB ZIP file for Linux
> 3. Extract the ZIP to an easily-accessible location (like the Desktop for example).
> 4. Open a Terminal window.
> 5. Enter the following command: `cd /path/to/extracted/folder/`
> 6. This will change the directory to where you extracted the ADB files. So for example: `cd /Users/Doug/Desktop/platform-tools/`
> 7. Connect your device to your Linux machine with your USB cable. Change the connection mode to “file transfer (MTP)” mode. This is not
>      always necessary for every device, but it’s recommended so you don’t
>      run into any issues.
> 8. Once the Terminal is in the same folder your ADB tools are in, you can execute the following command to launch the ADB daemon: adb
>      devices
> 9. Back on your smartphone or tablet device, you’ll see a prompt asking you to allow USB debugging. Go ahead and grant it.
>
> [image: ss1]
>
> 10. Finally, re-enter the command from step #8. If everything was successful, you should now see your device’s serial number in the
>       Terminal window output. Congrats! You can now run any ADB command on
>       your device! Now go forth and start modding your phone by following
>       our extensive list of tutorials!

**NOTE:** On Debian/Ubuntu you can install adb via `sudo apt-get install adb` for Redhat distros: `sudo yum install android-tools`.

#### References

- [How to Install ADB on Windows, macOS, and Linux](https://www.xda-developers.com/install-adb-windows-macos-linux/)
- [SDK Platform Tools release notes](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools)
- [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS - Install Android Tools (ADB, Fastboot & QtADB)](http://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/74-ubuntu/354-ubuntu-xenial-android-adb-fastboot-qtadb)
- [Android File Transfer For Linux](http://whoozle.github.io/android-file-transfer-linux/)
- [Oculus Go, adb and Linux](https://www.reddit.com/r/OculusGo/comments/8p9a8e/oculus_go_adb_and_linux/)

Comment: Sorry for my low effort question here. I had accepted this answer, however there is a bit more to setting up the Go with Linux.  I'm adding a separate answer and just want to note here that Android File Transfer does not work for the Go headset as MTP does not appear to be available at this time.

Comment: "Change the connection mode to “file transfer (MTP)” mode. ". I do not understand what this means.